# Не работает e.preventDefault() в Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Пишу проект на Yii2, и делаю одну кнопку, "Оценить", пользователь на нее нажимает, и аяксом данные должны передаться в контроллер и экшн, в опере и хроме срабатывает всё отлично, а Firefox не поддается ни в какую. То есть в фаерфоксе пользователя перекидывает по ссылке в этот экшн прямо в браузере.
 И да, прогуглил наверно весь интернет, не помогло. Версия Firefox - 52.0.1. Кто-то сталкивался с вот таким вообще? 
Вот все вариации которые я уже успел сделать, и которые не привели к успеху

```
$('.like-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

$('.like-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e = $.event.fix(e);
    e.preventDefault();

 $('.like-btn').on('click', function(event) { 
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
```

И конечно же вариант, где в конце return false; (тоже не сработал)

Yii2:

```
<?= Html::a(Html::button(Html::img(Yii::getAlias("@web") . '/images/like-unactive.png', 
  ['width' => '20px', 'class' => 'like-btn', 'data-id' => $photo->id ]),
  ['class' => 'floating-like', 'name' => 'like', 'value' => $photo->id]),
  ['profile/like', 'id' => $photo->id])
?>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/profile/like?id=50">
  <button type="button" class="floating-like" name="like" value="50">
    <img class="like-btn" src="/images/like-unactive.png" width="20px" alt="" data-id="50">
  </button>
</a>
```

Comment: должно работать. Код вообще в обработчик попадает?

Comment: если Вы имеете ввиду подгружается ли JS - то да, в испекторе глянул, и код именно тот, который я описал в одном из примерах. Почему не срабатывает приложить ума вообще не могу

Comment: я имел в виду, выполняется ли `function(e) { ...`. Вставьте туда первой строчкой `alert("Click");`.

Comment: Знаете, что странно, но действительно не попадает. Алерт не выводится. По какой причине такое может быть вообще?

Comment: пора показывать html

Comment: Не знаю знаете ли Yii2, но вот (да, тут картинка встроенная в кнопку, и кнопка встроенная в ссылку, ссылке задаю контроллер и action с ID фотографии на которой ставится "оценить") КОД:  <?= Html::a(Html::button(Html::img(Yii::getAlias("@web") . '/images/like-unactive.png', ['width' => '20px', 'class' => 'like-btn', 'data-id' => $photo->id ]), ['class' => 'floating-like', 'name' => 'like', 'value' => $photo->id]), ['profile/like', 'id' => $photo->id]) ?>

Comment: меня скорее интересует hmtl в браузере - "View page source". И, будьте добры, добавляйте, пожалуйста, код в вопрос - не в комментарии

Comment: Ну вот эта самая пикантная часть: <a href="/profile/like?id=50"><button type="button" class="floating-like" name="like" value="50"><img class="like-btn" src="/images/like-unactive.png" width="20px" alt="" data-id="50"></button></a>

Comment: Очень хорошо. Где находится на странице js код `$('.like-btn').on('click', function(e) { ...` по отношению к этому hmtl, выше или ниже? Завернут ли js код в `$(document).ready(function(){ ...`?

Comment: почему вам вообще понадобился preventDefault при клике на картинке?

Comment: @Igor JS подключается в head, всё время код был завернул в $(document).ready, сейчас убрал его, и эффект ровно тот же..

Comment: @vp_arth мне понадобился preventDefault при клике на ссылку ) как раз, чтобы браузер не переходил по ссылке как это сейчас происходит в фаерфоксе. У меня картинка встроена внутри кнопки, а кнопка встроена в ссылку.

Comment: Вы нигде не завертываете функцию полностью - возьмите пример с документации jQuery и работайте с ним. Код должен быть завершенным - 
$( ".like-btn" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault(); console.log('Do on click action now');
});

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Я вроде не показывал JS еще, я показывал вырезки, вот как сейчас там, после этого кода идут дальнейшие действия, и код закрывается. КОД:  $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('.like-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    
        e.preventDefault(); });
   
});

Comment: а-а-а, все понятно, сейчас напишу

Comment: @Igor сильно жду, буду очень благодарен, я уже часа 2-3 долблю эту тему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как верно углядел @vp_arth, Вы назначаете обработчик для `img`, но событие всплывает до `а`.

```
$('.like-btn').closest('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

Comment: Свершилось! Спасибо огромнейшее! Но вопрос почему оно работало в двух браузерах, а в одном нет - остается открытым для меня)

Comment: @idriverx да, согласен. Мне тоже хотелось бы разобраться. В качестве первого предположения: FF по-другому обрабатывает клики на элементы внутри линков, которые в стандартном случае должны вести к загрузке другой страницы.

Comment: Еще прошу прощения, а у меня эта запись выглядит наверно слишком усложненной? Упростить ее возможно? Я просто картинку внутри кнопки сделал, чтоб была не стандартная кнопка, а нужное изображение. И потому запись где 3 вложенных тэга мне кажется совсем не очень

Comment: @idriverx, просто перенесите класс-селектор прямо в ссылку.

Comment: @idriverx не совсем понятно, зачем Вам ссылка, которая не выглядит как ссылка и не работает как ссылка. Не достаточно ли оставить просто кнопку с картинкой, а обработчик вешать на кнопку?

Comment: @Igor действительно, мой затуп большой. Большое спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: @idriverx Не за что. Успехов в программировании!